# TensorFlow Keras: print out and save loss and gradients during model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient, loss

I'm training neural networks in TensorFlow Keras by using basic code like this:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Is there a way to print out and also save the loss function value, the gradients, and norm of the gradients, for each epoch of `model.fit`?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use ``callbacks`` to print and even save whatever you need. For example in CSV file (checkout ``CSVLogger callback``). For saving model variables you can also use ``callbacks`` and ``checkpoints``.

Comment: Thanks! And how do I compute the gradients during training?

Comment: If you are using custom training, ``tf.GradientTape()`` will do it for you, and then you can compute gradients using ``tape.gradient()`` function.

Comment: Or if you want to use ``model.fit()``, all variables stores in ``tf.Variable``. You can print them like this ``print(model.trainable_variables)``

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean I can only get the variables, but not the gradients if I use model.fit()? Can I also get the gradients with model.fit()? Or I have to do custom training?

Comment: No. you don't have to implement custom training. I have elaborated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print and save variables after each epoch during training, you can use [Callbacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback). You may write your own callback or use built-in callbacks.
For example of a built-in callback, [CSVLogger](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/CSVLogger) helps you to store each epoch results in a CSV file.

Also you may use [ModelCheckpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) in order to save weights after each epoch in checkpoints.

If you want to print gradients after each epoch, you have two possibilities.

Either write a custom training and use `tf.GradientTape()` to record operations for automatic differentiation, and then `tape.gradient()` function to compute gradients for you. See this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) for more information.

Or if you want to use `model.fit()`, you again should write a custom callback and then print variables in model like this: `print(model.trainable_variables)`.

Here is an example of custom callback:

```
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
   print(model.trainable_variables)

my_callback = myCallback()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, callbacks=[my_callback])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear! The only question I have is, in the example custom callback you gave, I should replace print(model.trainable_variables) with some other function in order to get the gradients, right? Seems that print(model.trainable_variables) only prints the variables, not the gradients.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by gradients? trainable_variables are actually weights and biases that updated, and after each epoch you can print them. gradients are computed after each iteration (not each epoch), and subtract from weights and bias.

Comment: Yes, I mean the gradients computed after each iteration. Namely, if the updates at each iteration are: trainable_variables = trainable_variables - step_size * gradients, I would like to get the value of these gradients.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, in this case you better to implement custom training. However there is a trick that may help you to get gradients. if you subtract weights and bias in each iteration you get gradients. Add this to your callback and compute difference of variables in each iteration. For computing in each iteration you can use ``on_batch_end`` function in your callback.